# Can't use FileFormatException (?)

Tags: c#, exception, xna

I'm currently writing a custom importer for my small XNA project and am trying to do something as simple as throwing a [`FileFormatException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileformatexception.aspx) in my importer `Import` method.

I have referenced `WindowsBase.dll`, so `FileFormatException` should be available under `System.IO` in IntelliSense, right? I type `System.IO` and there is no autocomplete with `FileFormatException` under `System.IO`.

Here is where the throw statement is located:

```
namespace TetrominoImporter
{
    public class TetrominoReader : ContentImporter<Tetromino>
    {
        public const string blockFileName = "blocks.txt";

        public override Tetromino Import(string filename, ContentImporterContext context)
        {
            // HERE
```

Comment: Ok I'm a complete idiot, thanks to you ofstream, I have just noticed my OTHER (importer) project didn't reference WindowsBase, my main project did (which is useless). And that code is in the importer. Sorry guys, I feel stupid for asking. It's like I couldn't see that error because it was just in front of me.

Could you set your post as an answer, S Grimminck, so that I accept it ? (I think it's how it works ?) Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to include WindowsBase in your references, as FileFormatException is defined within that assembly. Once you've added that, you should be able to resolve System.IO.FileFormatException